# Animate via Horizontal/Vertical offset of ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I need to have control whose position is directly correlated by the scroll offset of a ScrollViewer in Windows Phone 8 SDK (silverlight/wpf). Additionally I need to be able to tell what the scroll offset in a delegate of sorts so that I may change other in-app properties. Is this even possible?

I have looked all over but can not seem to find any example, nor do I seem to have a grasp of WPF/Silverlight's animation concepts enough to pick this up.

The best that I could come up with is shown below. It would appear at first to work, but unfortunately will only update when your finger is not down and the ScrollViewer is not animating, so the updates come too infrequently. I need the updates to come as a part of the animation loop, so every frame or so (60-100+ per second), I get the new scroll offset value. Is there any way to schedule the DispatchTimer in the animation loop? Or would there be some sort of better way to approach this entirely, using something like DependentProperties?

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
        t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(16.6);
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(
            (object s, EventArgs ee) =>
                {
                    // FunkBox is some ListBox
                    ScrollViewer sv = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(FunkBox);
                    if (sv == null) 
                    {
                        // TOffset is some TextBlock
                        TOffset.Text = "dur...";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TOffset.Text = String.Format("dur {0}", sv.HorizontalOffset);
                    }
                });
        t.Start();
    }

    static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
            for (int i = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
            {
                var child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null)
                {
                    return typedChild;
                }
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a red herring answer for a few moments; I've updated my answer now and tested it works, below.

Answer (score 3):

This took me a while to figure out too.  Here's how you do it:

- Ensure that your ScrollViewer has ManipulationMode set to 'Control'
- Walk through the visual tree to find the Vertical Scrollbar child of the ScrollViewer.
- Hook into its ValueChanged event.

So, you XAML would be:

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="mainScrollViewer" ManipulationMode="Control">
        ....
 </ScrollViewer>
```

And your code behind:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollBar verticalBar;
        verticalBar = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(mainScrollViewer, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
        verticalBar.ValueChanged += verticalBar_ValueChanged;
    }

    void verticalBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double newVerticalOffset =  e.NewValue;
        // Set the offset of your other control here, using newVerticalOffset
    }
```

or, for a ListBox, you would need to get the ScrollViewer from inside the Listbox using code such as:

```
    ScrollViewer mainScrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(yourListBoxControl);
    // ...then use the code above

    public T GetVisualChild<T>(UIElement parent) where T : UIElement
    {
        T child = null; // default(T);

        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            UIElement element = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = element as T;
            if (child == null)
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(element);
            if (child != null)
                break;
        }

        return child;
    }
```

You might also need to set the manipulation mode of the ScrollViewer in your constructor:

```
    ScrollViewer mainScrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(lstTest);
    sv.ManipulationMode = ManipulationMode.Control;
```

Comment: Great, hope it works for you - please mark this as the Answer if it does, or let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Would there be any way to accomplish this with a `ListBox`?

Comment: Yes, see my edit above - I'm not 100% sure it's the same as WPF but give it a go.

Comment: @samuraisam Was this the correct answer?  If so, please mark it as such.